# Does Cubase 8 Artist work well in Windows 10?

Tags: cubase, compatibility, windows-10

Does anyone know if Cubase 8 Artist work well in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is compatible:

[image]

By far most of their other products are compatible too (only a few known issues with some hardware products).

([offical Steinberg source](https://www.steinberg.net/nc/en/support/knowledgebase_new/show_details/kb_show/product-compatibility-info-regarding-microsoft-windows-10.html))